# trying to make this show in my snippet once called any ideas how to keep all these quotes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

"magazine"  ,"",

for some reason it wont show and only shows as :

magazine

if anyone know please help trying to make a code snippet extension for a modding community to help out beginners

Comment: Would it be possible to add a runnable snippet for the community to see and help diagnose the issue?

Comment: Escape them as in `\"magazine\",\"\",`